# Какой знак препинания после "какая разница"?

Tags: пунктуация

Что никак не соображу, какой знак препинания нужен в предложении: "Какая разница() тут он или нет?" Есть варианты: двоеточие или запятая. А что скажет ученое сообщество?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Какая разница, тут он или нет?-запятая, потому что это изъяснительное придаточное. Роль подчинительного союза здесь играет союз ИЛИ: § 2792. Изъяснительная связь оформляется союзами и союзными частицами ли... ли, ли... или, или... или, или, то ли... то ли, если вопрос, содержащийся в придаточном предложении, является открытым. Такой вопрос чаще бывает полным  и значительно реже - частичным .
   1) Не знаю, обманут ли был я, Осмеян тобой или нет... (Лерм.); Какое дело нам, страдал ты или нет? 
http://rusgram.narod.ru/2765-2787.html